# Convolution of functions with compact support

Tags: measure-theory, convolution

I have a question regarding convolution with compact support:

Suppose $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $g \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, and both of them have compact support.

Show that $f*g$ (convolution integral of $f$ and $g$) has compact support.

Kindly advise in proceeding the working.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the integral, and try to see for what values of $x$ the convolution can have a value $\neq 0$.

Comment: I suppose if f has compact support K1, g has compact support k2, then f*g should have compact support on (k1 intersect k2). But I can't prove it rigorously in the sense of I try to use Holder's inequality to prove that f*g is zero on the complement of (k1 intersect k2), but on the other hand, I cannot show that f*g is non zero on (k1 intersect k2). Kindly advise.

Comment: No, it's not the intersection. What is the integral that gives you $(f\ast g)(x)$?

Comment: Apologies, I do not understand what you refer to. $(f*g)(x)=\int (f(y)g(x-y)dy$

Comment: Right. Now, the integral (the value of the convolution at $x$) can only be nonzero if the integrand is nonzero in at least one point. A product is nonzero when both factors are nonzero. So, 1) when can $f(y)$ be nonzero, and 2) for these $y$, when can $g(x-y)$ be nonzero?

Comment: Ok. For f(y), not to be on zero, it will be on the set of compact support, ie K1. Then for these y, x-y will not be zero if x-y is in K2. Therefore x is in y+K2, which means x is in K1+K2? So the set is K1+K2 which is the compact support for f*g?

Comment: You are a little too affirmative, but in principle, that's it. If $x$ is outside of $K_1 + K_2$, the supports of $f(y)$ and $g(x-y)$ don't intersect, so then $(f\ast g)(x) = 0$. If $x \in K_1 + K_2$, then $(f\ast g)(x)$ _may_ be nonzero. The integral can be zero even if the integrand isn't identically $0$. So you have the support of $f\ast g$ contained in $K_1 + K_2$, in general, you can't say they are equal.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. So for the question,  does it suffices to show that the support of f*g is contained in K1+K2? Or I have to do something extra. Kindly advise.:)

Comment: That depends on what you can assume goes without saying. You may need to explicitly say that thus the support is a closed subset of a compact set and hence compact, or it may be that that can be considered evident. Probably you need to say it.

Comment: Ya that makes sense. Afterall, compact support needs the set involved to be compact. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We define $f \ast g (x)$ to be

$$ f \ast g(x) = \int f(y)g(x-y) dy$$

If this integral is to be nonzero, there must be some overlap between the support of $f$ and the support of $g(x-y)$. What does changing $x$ do to the support of $g(x-y)$? If both $f$ and $g$ are compact support, can you see why taking $x$ large enough will force the supports of the functions in the integral to be disjoint?