Convolution of $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ is analytic
Suppose that we have two real functions $f$ and $g$ both belonging to $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. Is the convolution (assumed to be well defined) defined as:
$$(f*g)(x) = \int_\mathbb{R}f(x-z)g(z)dz$$
an analytic function ?
Otherwise, under which conditions the convolution is analytic ?
Any references or solutions will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

No, take $f, g$ to be nonzero functions with compact support. Then $f \ast g$ is nonzero and has compact support (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533537/convolution-of-functions-with-compact-support), but the only analytic function on $\Bbb R$ with compact support is the zero function.

Thank you @TravisWillse for this counter example! What about the case where neither $f$ and $g$ have compact support ?

If neither $f$ nor $g$ has compact support, I would worry about whether the convolution is even defined. Take $f=g=1$. Then $f \ast g = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1 dx=...$

Thank you @Chris, but I already assume that the convolution is well defined.

Ah good point. Sorry for the unnessary comment then. I will still leave it though so the comment section stays comprehensive.
